# use plugin for neo4j: too many threads

Tags: neo4j

I use my plugin for Neo4j. It's execute more than one hundred by hour. After than I see more than one hundred threads. Can I must close this threads? I must close each thread from plugin?

TIA.

UPD. I disable all my concurrency, but it doesn't help. 15 queries to neo4j give over 50 threads. Each next success query increase thread count by 3-4. If result of the query is empty, than thread count do not increase. Where is bug? in my plugin?

Comment: it depends on what you execute. What is your software setup? I suspect there are some threads that you are not closing.

Comment: I disable all my concurrency, but it doesn't help. 15 queries to neo4j give over 50 threads. Each next success query increase thread count by 3-4. If result of the query is empty, than thread count do not increase. Where is bug? in my plugin?

Comment: There is problem in my plugin. Sorry for trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error of statsd threads. Sorry for trouble.